# Customizing indentation style for continuation lines?

Tags: indentation, cc-mode

I would like to customize the `"k&r"` indentation style, so that continuation lines are indented 8 spaces, like this:

```
if (first
        && second) { // <- 8 spaces.
    third();
}
```

--

CLARIFICATION: Basically, I would like to distinguish easily between a block header and nested statements, to avoid confusion; for example:

```
if (first
    && second) { // <- Block header (4 spaces).
    third();     // <- Nested statement (same 4 spaces).
}
```

I have seen some code indented like the following, to address the above issue:

```
if (first
    && second) {  // <- Block header (4 spaces).
        third();  // <- Nested statement (8 spaces).
}
```

But, to me, the above indentation looks confusing. I would rather have the opposite indentation:

```
if (first
        && second) { // <- Block header (8 spaces).
    third();         // <- Nested statement (4 spaces).
}
```

Such a differentiation would suffice. Function arguments inside a block header should be distinguishable, too, but - in that case - the actual amount of indentation would not matter:

```
if (first 
        && second        // <- Block header (8 spaces).
        && third(        // <- Block header (8 spaces).
              fourth)) { // <- Function argument (any indentation).
    fifth();             // <- Nested statement (4 spaces).
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "continuation line"?  E.g. why do you consider `&& ...` a continuation line but not `}`?  After all, you could write the whole thing on a single line.

Comment: @Stefan I have added a clarification.

Comment: Thanks.  BTW, I believe this is one of the reasons why the GNU Coding Standard recommends breaking lines before infix operators rather than after them: even if the indentation of `&& second` is the same as that of `third();` the leading `&&` is a tell-tale sign that this is not the beginning of a block.

Comment: @Stefan Yup, that is what I do already. I wonder why I wrote my example code differently... I am editing my question to reflect that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to modify [`c-offsets-alist`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/c_002doffsets_002dalist.html) for the "K&R" style by creating a new style and using that. Something like the following should work.

```el
(c-add-style "my/k&r"
    '("k&r"
      (c-offsets-alist
       (statement-cont . 3))))
(setq c-default-style "my/k&r")
```

This creates a new `cc-mode` style called "my/k&r" based on "k&r", sets the syntactic element `statement-cont` (A continuation of a C (or like) statement.) to a *relative offset* of 3. (The default value of `c-basic-offset` is 5 in the "k&r" style.) Then, we set the default style to the style we just created.

Note that there are *multiple* syntactic elements that control "continuation" lines. I picked `statement-cont` for my example as it's the most generic. Please see the documentation in the manual for [`c-offsets-alist`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/c_002doffsets_002dalist.html), and within Emacs via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> c-offsets-alist <kbd>Return</kbd>. The EmacsWiki page on [Indenting C](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC) also has some good examples of creating/modifying styles.